# How to add custom form and insert data into database in alfresco 5.2

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-maven

In my alfresco project have requirement for add custom form and data will be store in database.

I would like to submit one form having user name & password fields in it. After click on submit button how can I handle request in backend so it will use Alfresco to process request and store details in database.

I am ready to do this in spring, maven or any java technology but please suggest me how i customize alfresco with custom web form.

I have reefer these links but i have not getting proper answer.
https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-6010-web-quick-start-installation-and-configuration#w_configuringwebquickstart

https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5527-cmis

Comment: To me, you need to be clearer. It is hard to understand what you want.

Comment: Use the Alfresco NG2 components to build something in Angular that stores using the Alfresco REST APIs? If you know Angular you should be able to knock something up in about 30 minutes, I've seen it done in demos at conferences!

Comment: Sir i don't know Angular so i want to do with java code.
This option i get from internet but i want to with the JAVA.

Comment: Web Quick Start is aimed at Web Content Management, required coding to fully use, and has long since been dropped! You need to one of: write something using Share, write something using the new Angular NG2 stuff, or write your own custom code using the Alfresco services

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the existing Alfresco Share client by configuring forms that allow you to edit properties on folders and documents where those properties are defined using custom types and aspects, then follow [this tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html).

If you do not want to be constrained by the Alfresco Share client then you must write a custom application.

The Alfresco NG2 components were suggested to you, but you would prefer to use Java. So use whatever Java framework you do know and then communicate with Alfresco remotely using CMIS via the [OpenCMIS Client for Java](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html).

If you are just building a custom form that captures arbitrary data and stores it in a back-end (relational or otherwise), and your requirements have nothing to do with documents, then you should not be using Alfresco at all.